# How to do form submit from the jquery fancy box to the spring controller class?

Tags: jquery, spring, fancybox

I have a jquery document ready function of containing a fancy box for which I provide an html to render and I need to submit that form from fancy box and take it to the controller class of spring.

Whenever a Checkbox is checked, A fancy box appears, codes below

Here is my jquery fancy box code

```
$("input:checkbox")
  .click(
  function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form:form method="POST" action="mapping">' +
          '<label> Map the Selected field to Category ?   </label>'
      +
          '<select name="category" id="category">' +
          '<option>COMPANY NAME</option>' +
          '<option>LINE OF BUSINESS 1</option>' +
          '</select>'
      +
          '<input type="button" name="mapBtn" id="mapBtn" value="MAP" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all"' +
          '</form:form></div>';
      $.fancybox
        .open(
        htmlStr, {
          'width': 950,
          'height': 1100,
          'autoScale': false,
          'transitionIn': 'none',
          'transitionOut': 'none',
          'hideOnContentClick': false
        });
    }
  });
```

controller code is below

```
@PostMapping("mapping")
public String mapCategory()throws Exception{
  try {
    System.out.println("Welcome to mapping funcion");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }

  return "viewUploadedExcel";
}
```

Since I am new to both the areas I explore it here.
Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an [Ajax POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Request to your Controller.

```
$( "#formButton" ).click(function() {
        sendForm();
    });
function sendForm(){
    var data = $("#form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost/mapping",
       data: data
    }).done(function(responseData) {
       console.log(responseData)
   });
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the expected result can u please tell how ajax works with my fancy box html

Comment: You need to replace the #formButton with the button id in your form(mapBtn). also you need to add csrf protection to your form. For Form submission with spring checkout this guide(https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) After that you are able to fix your from. Your action is not correct defined. Also in your Controller the PostMapping is not right for my given js code snippet. Should be @PostMapping("/mapping").

Comment: I also updated my given js codeslippend. The serialization of the form values needs to be inside the sendForm Function. So it serializes the data on every submit form event

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution myself,

```
                $( "#mapBtn" ).click(function() {
                        sendForm();
                             });
                function sendForm(){
                    alert('alert');    
                    var selVal= $('#category option:selected').val();
                    alert(selVal);
                    $.ajax({                                        
                    url : "mapping",
                    data :{selected: selVal},
                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type : 'POST',
                    success : function(result) {
                    alert("success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Used Ajax call and got the success result.